# Dask where returns NaN on valid array

Tags: numpy, dask, numpy-ndarray, zarr

I'm trying to accelerate my `numpy` code using `dask`. Following is a part of my `numpy` code

```
arr_1 = np.load('<arr1_path>.npy')
arr_2 = np.load('<arr2_path>.npy')
arr_3 = np.load('<arr3_path>.npy')

arr_1 = np.concatenate((arr_1, arr_2[:,:,np.newaxis]),axis = 2)
arr_1_half = totaldata.shape[0]//2
arr_4 = arr_3[:half]
[r,c] = np.where(arr_4 == True)
[rn,cn] = np.where(arr_4 == False)

print(len(r))
```

This prints valid results and is working fine. However, following `dask` equivalent

```
arr_1 = da.from_zarr('<arr1_path>.zarr')
arr_2 = da.from_zarr('<arr2_path>.zarr')
arr_3 = da.from_zarr('<arr3_path>.zarr')

arr_1 = da.concatenate((arr_1, arr_2[:,:,np.newaxis]),axis = 2)
arr_1_half = totaldata.shape[0]//2
arr_4 = arr_3[:half]
[r,c] = da.where(arr_4 == True)
[rn,cn] = da.where(arr_4 == False)

print(len(r)) # <----- Error: float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

results in `r` as

```
dask.array<getitem, shape=(nan,), dtype=int64, chunksize=(nan,), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
```

and thus the above mentioned error. Since `dask` arrays are lazily evaluated, do I have to explicitly call `compute()` or similar somewhere? Or am I missing something basic? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What version of zarr? See https://zarr.readthedocs.io/en/stable/release.html#release-2-11-1

Comment: Installed it yesterday using `conda`, just checked it's the latest version 2.11.1. Also, I ran the same `numpy` code using `zarr.load()` instead of `np.load()` and it seems to be working fine. The issue I think is with `dask` instead of `zarr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array you've constructed with `da.where` has [unknown chunk sizes](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/array-chunks.html#unknown-chunks), which can happen whenever the size of an array depends on lazy computations that haven’t yet been performed. Unknown values within shape or chunks are designated using np.nan rather than an integer, which is why you see the `ValueError` ([this error message was improved](https://github.com/dask/dask/commit/2e5bab9804109c0d5be7ff034b184e1cd6005350) in the last few months). The solution is to use [`compute_chunk_sizes`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.array.Array.compute_chunk_sizes.html#dask.array.Array.compute_chunk_sizes):

```py
import dask.array as da
x = da.from_array(np.random.randn(100), chunks=20)
y = x[x > 0]
# len(y) # ValueError: Cannot call len() on object with unknown chunk size.
y.compute_chunk_sizes() # modifies y in-place
len(y)
```